# Data streams re-use across Flink transformations

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a DataStream (let's say inStream) on which I need to apply two different lists of transformations to generate two different output streams (let's say outStream1 and outStream2).

inStream is also constructed after applying a complex list of transformations on the source stream.

Now, my question is that since inStream needs to be reused across two branches of transformations, is there a way to cache this inStream and reuse it across the 2 branches ?

The way this problem is solved in Spark is using rdd.cache() method wherein inStream is cached in memory and re-used across transformations. I want to know whether some similar such construct exists in Flink to solve this.

Another question is that how does program execution get triggered in Flink ?
In Spark, program is lazily evaluated and execution gets triggered when a Spark action is encountered.

As per my understanding (please correct, if wrong) of Flink, Flink JobManager creates an execution graph which decides program flow. But, does it do the above specified DataStream reusing on its own ?

Thanks

Comment: If i am not wrong, you are trying to do inStream.map(transformation1) and in.map(transformation2), i didn't really get what you meant by "instream is also constructed after applying a complex list of transformations on the source stream" but as Flink is an event processor so apart from windows I am not really aware of caching of data in Flink.

Comment: Hi Biplob
Is caching required (as is the case with Spark) while re-using streams or is it automatically handled by Flink system ?

Comment: Nope, if you are working on flink data streams, you shouldn't require caching. I can imagine caching being used only in case of batch programs (using datasets API) but even in that case Flink automatically optimizes that.